# Prolog Queries is returning wrong boolean value

Tags: prolog, prolog-toplevel

so I have a fact `weather(jan, 17, cold, wind, snow).`
 and rule

```
match(W,D,T) :-
      weather(W,D,T,_,_)
  ;   weather(W,D,_,T,_)
  ;   weather(W,D,_,_,T).
```

When I type `match(jan, 17, wind).` Prolog returns `true; false.` I want it to only return true, but it's returning false as well, how can I fix this?

Comment: Your definition of `weather/5` has some built-in ambiguity since the 3rd, 4th, and 5th arguments can interchangeably mean anything. Therefore, if you try to write a suitably general predicate like `match/3`, it's going to have choice points. When you see `true` as a prompt, that means Prolog succeeded but there was a choice point it needs to go back to check for another possible solution (since, if it were in the database, `weather(jan, 17, wind, snow, cold)` would also be a possible valid fact that would match). Prolog will eventually give `false` when it finds no more solutions. Normal.

Comment: You could use cuts, as @Zebollo suggested, which would prune the choice point, but then you'd lose the generality of the solution. It would not yield multiple results for queries that legitimately have multiple solutions.

Answer (score -1):

I discourage the use of the ";" (OR) operator (unreadable code).
This is what you should have written:

```
match(W,D,T) :-
    weather(W,D,T,_,_),
    !.
match(W,D,T) :-
    weather(W,D,_,T,_),
    !.
match(W,D,T) :-
    weather(W,D,_,_,T).
```

Your previous code "returns" true and false because of backtracking. There is nothing wrong with that.